# Graphics DrawImage, FillRectangle, and DrawCell on cells in C1FlexGrid

Tags: c#, cell, system.drawing, c1flexgrid

I'm having a difficult time correctly rendering cells in a C1FlexGrid when I need to set a background color, draw an image, and fill a rectangle for a wide border. I can't seem to get the right combination of DrawCell, DrawImage, and FillRectangle for each cell to draw properly.

The "OwnerDrawCell" event is where I am drawing the contents, border, and image.

First I am setting the cell backcolor of each cell to something like this:

```
e.Style.BackColor = lockedBackColor;
```

Then for *some* cells I am drawing an image and text.

```
// CENTER TEXT IN CELL; IMAGE IS RIGHT JUSTIFIED, CENTERED VERTICALLY
// Must draw cell first - background color, borders, etc..
e.DrawCell(DrawCellFlags.Background | DrawCellFlags.Border);

// Draw cell text
int textWidth = (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(e.Text, e.Style.Font).Width;
int textHeight = (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(e.Text, e.Style.Font).Height;
float textCenterX = e.Bounds.Left + ((e.Bounds.Width - textWidth) / 2);
float textCenterY = e.Bounds.Top + ((e.Bounds.Height - textHeight) / 2);
e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Text, e.Style.Font, brushColorForString, textCenterX, textCenterY);

if (e.Row == 8 || PlantHasBins())
{
    // Draw cell image
    int cellImageX = e.Bounds.Right - _cellImage.Width;
    int cellImageY = e.Bounds.Top + ((e.Bounds.Height - _cellImage.Height) / 2);
    var cellImagePoint = new Point(cellImageX, cellImageY);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_cellImage, cellImagePoint);
}

e.Handled = true;
```

Then for *some* columns I want to draw a heavy right border to give a visual separation between groups of columns.

```
e.DrawCell(DrawCellFlags.Border);

Rectangle rc;
Margins m = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
m.Right = 3;
CellRange rg;

rg = PlantAlleyBinGrid.GetCellRange(e.Row, e.Col);
rc = e.Bounds;
rg.c1 = rg.c2 = 2 + 1;
rg.c1 = rg.c2 = 2;

rc.X = rc.Right - m.Right;
rc.Width = m.Right;
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), rc);

e.Handled = true;
```

The code as written is almost there. I've tried many alternatives and flows but it ends up not drawing the cell image, the cell border, the cell contents, or any combination thereof.

I need help on how to draw everything on a cell.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by calling DrawCell and DrawString for cells that do not draw an image.